# Find an equation of a quartic function with 2 points and a tangent point

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find an equation of a quartic function if the curve passes through the points  $(-3,0)$, $(-1,0)$ and is tangent to the $x$-axis at $(2,0)$

Answer (score 4):

The tangent point represents a repeated root. Thus you have been given all four roots of the quartic.